# The corect use of the verb "leave" in context

Tags: word-choice

Tell me please if I used the verb *leave* correctly in this context.

> Person 1: How many sets of squats do you have **left** to do?
>
> Person 2: I have 2 sets **left**.

If the sentences don't sound natural, tell me please how to say it correctly.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to think there is a problem here?

Comment: I made these sentences, and I am not a native, so I am not sure I used the verb correctly.

Comment: Yes, but why did you ask about "left" and not about "sets"  Why do you think the word "sets" is used correctly but you are uncertain about the word "left".

Comment: Because I heard natives use the word "set" when talking weightlifting. What would you call it?

Comment: I'd use "set", there is no mistake.  Now why are you uncertain about "left"? Have you heard people say "I have two cookies left" or "I have two hours left"?  I'm trying to understand what your problem is. If you haven't heard native English speakers say this, why do you think it could be correct?

Comment: I had a feeling that it was correct, but wasn't completely sure. And I don't remember if I heard natives say it, so I asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of "left" is quite natural in these examples.